# In what line of what file does the block reward depend on?

Tags: development, block, altcoin

I want to make an altcoin and since I am new, I wanted to know what sets the reward of a block after being mined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.cpp:

```
int64_t GetBlockValue(int nHeight, int64_t nFees)
{
    int64_t nSubsidy = 50 * COIN;

    // Subsidy is cut in half every 210,000 blocks which will occur approximately every 4 years.
    nSubsidy >>= (nHeight / Params().SubsidyHalvingInterval());

    return nSubsidy + nFees;
}
```

miner.cpp (within CreateNewBlock):

```
pblock->vtx[0].vout[0].nValue = GetBlockValue(pindexPrev->nHeight+1, nFees);
```